Slur directed at LGBTQ colleague during company holiday party - should I have said anything more as a manager and fellow colleague?
I am a manager in my company since about 7 years ago. I work in IT division of a company in the non-IT sector.
Last week, our company had the annual holiday party where employees were free to bring a guest. A cash bar was on site and all colleagues I was at the table with had been drinking (about 2 drinks estimated), including myself. While talking to my colleagues, one of them introduced her wife as her plus 1 guest.

At this point, another colleague not in my division and for whom I had only met that night for the first time, immediately backed away from the table and said dirty faggot, a directed slur at members of the LGBTQ community.

The crass and discriminatory remark shocked me as an utter breach of professional decorum. In my surprised state of mind, I was initially lost for words but then I said to the person who said the slur "not cool" and "please be mindful of professional boundaries" Afterward I went to another table with the colleague and her wife to escape the discomfort.
Other than saying to my colleague that sorry she experienced such disrespect and that I am an ally of the LGBTQ community with friends who are gay/lesbian, I did not mention this incident further since it happened.
I am a manager, but not in this colleague's reporting hierarchy and the company party was the first time I met the remote colleague whom made the rude remark.
Questions

Did I overstep in how I responded or on the flip side, under react?

How else could I have supported my colleague and her wife in this scenario?



What’s your company’s policy on this sort of infraction? Alcohol causes people to say things that they might otherwise keep to themselves, it doesn’t make those thoughts right, but as long as they don’t say those things out loud or otherwise break the law we as humans are allowed those feelings. The question you’ll have to ask, at what part of the event was it at, was this at the beginning (where everyone was having a good time) or at the end of night and perhaps had stopped being a company party.

What is the cultural background at your location? If it is the insult I read it as, you may have under-reacted. On the other hand, if everyone talks that way, then maybe not. What would have happened if a guy's wife had been called "ugly bitch" or something like that? Would the appropriate reaction have been to move away and ignore it?

Does sexual orientation even matter for this issue? Your coworker insulted another coworker and their guest. Intentionally and without any reason.

@nvoigt, it's a specific and directed slur aimed solely at lgbtq folks. I think that changes meaning and intent

@Michael It matters because it is not an intrapersonal problem. The person is prejudiced and abusive to a group of people. It is the literal definition of hate speech.

@Anthony - The slur directed towards the employee was the problem not the type of slur, or it shouldn’t be more or less offensive. I will again ask, what is the company policy, in a situation like this?

I'm a big fan of "not cool" and "we don't do that here." Had the colleague made some sort of attempt at a joke (did you meet playing softball? which one of you brought the U-Haul on your third date?) then your response would have been perfect. However, the word "dirty" is unambiguous. This isn't friendly or banter. It's a flat-out deliberate slur with no attempt to hide the negative feelings.
In the moment, letting the colleague and the targeted people know you don't share the sentiment is important, but it's not enough. I would recommend reporting the incident with the name of the person to your manager. Focus not on how you think the targeted people felt, but about how you felt hearing that. What I mean is, don't report on behalf of someone else, but on behalf of yourself. You didn't want to hear that. You were shocked, etc.
I might also take a moment to think about alcohol at company events. For some reason a lot of people who are able to be polite and professional all day long reveal a very unpleasant side after 2 or 3 drinks. I would prefer to maintain the illusion than to see that side of someone I have to keep working with afterwards.

Good point about the alcohol. However, I'd also suggest that there's some personal responsibility to be taken by someone who drinks too much at company events. You know you're at a company event, and that actions taken at the company event will reflect on you not only as a person, but as a worker/employee.

Where I come from the rule in court is: Being under the influence of alcohol counts as "mitigating circumstances" unless you put yourself into that state yourself. So if you go to the bar, have a drink or two, and then insult people, that's your full responsibility.

I'd say you under-reacted, you might not be this person's manager but you are a manager and as such you're carrying a degree of representing the company in events like this. Especially when considering how a company employee is behaving in front of an invited guest who isn't one.
While it isn't necessarily your place to discipline the offending colleague directly it's absolutely your place to get in touch with your management peer who is in their reporting line. There's an argument to be made that it's reasonable to ask the affected party if there's a specific course of action they would like the company to take I'd say that there's a disciplinary need beyond just that - comments of that sort would still warrant actioning if it were directed at a random member of the public who wasn't in the same position to speak to further action for example.

Can confirm, at least in my company as a manager I have a reporting duty for workplace incidents, and it would trigger a serious investigation (either conducted by the employee's line manager and HR, or an external company).

@xLeitix - That reporting duty extend beyond working hours? Keep in mind this slur was thrown outside the office at a Christmas party, it doesn’t make it any less offensive it alcohol was involved

@Donald Unclear if it would also apply if I just randomly ran into a colleague on my holiday in Hawaii, but a Christmas party, even if off-hours, is certainly a work function and reporting duties definitely apply to that.

This reminded me of a hypothetical question I had. When is it OK for someone to remain neutral and when is it 'expected' for a witness to speak up? If everyone at the table didn't respond, would they be complicit?

There are slurs and there are slurs.
The one used by this colleague is totally unacceptable and inexcusable and requires IMO that HR is informed and takes action. And this needs to happen without the insulted lady having to take any action by herself, so that no stories can come up in the future that she caused a man to be fired, but to make it clear that he did this himself.
Should you have reacted stronger? Sure, you should, but that situation would have come unexpected to anyone. You would expect some insult (not really expect, but things happen) but nothing like this.

I'd say you reacted well in the moment (making a huge scene directly would have arguably been counter-productive), but you are not done yet. What now needs to happen is that you report this incident up whatever chain your company has for discrimination or harassment issues. As a manager, you should be aware of what this chain looks like, if not your line manager and/or HR can support you.
I have never worked in the USA, but here in Sweden this is what it would look like for me:

[Immediately] Note down a memory protocol of the situation. What was said precisely, by whom, and who witnessed it?
[The next work day] Report the incident to your own line manager and HR. Ask for instructions for further steps. If your company has a mandatory reporting system for harassment cases (my company in Sweden has, and I believe it is a legal requirement for companies of a certain size) fill out a report there. As a manager, I would have a legal requirement to report harassment cases I observed (regular employees can report, managers must report - independently of whether any of the involved people are under my reporting line or not).
[Await further instructions - but in my company I would expect a call from HR within hours] Most likely your part in this is mostly done. HR will task the manager of the perpetrator (and likely their manager plus a few levels up) to start an investigation. This can be done either by the managers themselves (usually with close HR support), or through an external company (there are companies in Sweden that can conduct harassment investigations that they guarantee are in fulfilment of the applicable national laws, with the advantage that they (a) know how to do it and (b) are impartial). It's up to the perpetrators's management chain to decide which, if any, consequences are in order after the investigation has concluded (in my company I would be surprised if the outcome is anything else than immediate dismissal, but your mileage my vary). Your involvement at this point would exclusively be as a "witness" in the investigation, and for this it's good to have your memory protocol - you have no further skin in the game, and you have resolved yourself from any further responsibility by properly reporting. Do not expect to be "kept in the loop" or anything like this, it's likely that HR will want to play this relatively close to their chest, and it's not "your" case, it's a case for the perpetrator's manager.


Most discrimination policies at companies here in the US more or less require that managers report cases of harassment. Generally such matters are considered harassment if they are repeated/consistent, or severe. This particular case, with the words said, would definitely clear that "severe" threshold for me.
From the harassment training I've had at various companies, what you've outlined here largely parallels most US companies as well, and is a very well-written and well-thought-out answer.

@DoktorJ Agree, but ultimately it's not OP's duty to judge if the words that have been said in the context they have been said in are sufficiently severe to qualify for harassment. That's what the investigation is for.

My point was more that it was definitely offensive enough to warrant reporting. Making a UHaul joke or the like, yeah that'd be in poor taste, but probably not rise to the threshold of something reportable. The words that were said by the offender in this case though—100% can and should report.

I'd say your actions were fine. You made it clear that the behaviour was not acceptable and then removed yourself and your LBGTQ colleague from the situation; it sounds like you didn't have formal authority to do anything else on the night.
Honestly, the question here is whether your LBGTQ colleague wishes to take this any further; you could contact them and simply state that you would confirm what happened on the night if they did wish to take things further.

In my experience, at least on paper, the expectation is that any employee should be able to raise cases of harassment. It does not have to be the target of the harassment to decide if or how to pursue it. And, given that the asker is part of management and leadership of the organization, I'd say that the need to report the behavior is even stronger to set a good example for other employees.

@ThomasOwens - Agreed. Our company policy is that managers are always required to report this kind of incident. Of course, other companies may have other policies, so YMMV.

@ThomasOwens But what if the LGBTQ staff member doesn't want to escalate the issue?  Ideally, it should be reported, but if the person being harassed doesnt want it reported, it complicates things.  You very well may cause more stress for them and wind up driving them away from the company when they did nothing wrong.

It's not obvious to me that it's relevant whether or not this particular LGBTQ colleague wants to see things taken further. Calling a person by an anti-LGBTQ slur isn't just harassment against that particular person; it's harassment against all LGBTQ people who heard the slur. Refraining from "taking things further" would send the message that using slurs at company events is sometimes okay.

@JMac That is a valid concern and there is no one right answer. However, I would say that the right thing to do is to escalate. The one individual who is harassing and possible discriminating based on sexual orientation could drive away many individuals or cause broader issues for the company. I would risk two people over an entire group plus company reputation and standing. But someone else's ethical analysis could result in a different answer.

@ThomasOwens It's not the "risking two people" that I'd be particularly worried about.  I'd be more worried that you're making an already shitty situation worse for the LGBTQ employee, which just seems cruel.  Not saying the harassed employee should ignore it, but if that's what they wanted to do, escalating it it a way that involves the LGBTQ employee  (if you havent asked them about it) might make the situation worse for them.  Protecting the company is important, but if doing so causes more issues for the LGBTQ employee, it could come across as the company not caring about the harassed one.

@JMAc - I actually think that, in that this was directly witnessed by the manager, it stops being about the employee it was directed at - someone, at the very least, used an unacceptable slur at the company party.  The manager has a clear duty to report it. There's edge cases, for sure (offcolor jokes might just need a quiet word), but this is pretty egregious. Plus, the manager can be a witness, and doesn't need to involve the employee directly - they saw it happen, they can report it. It's pretty clear cut to me.

If an employee has come to you to say that someone made these remarks in private, I'd take their views into account about escalations. But OP has a variety of other people who heard the remark who can be witnesses for HR. Ask LGBTQ employee if she wants to escalate, and if not try to keep her out of it and get the other people to come forward as witnesses.

@SophieSwett agreed, for example if they had made the same statement while talking about some LGBT+ public figure instead of directly at a colleague, it would also be completely unacceptable and I would not want to work with such a person.

@JMac Could you explain how you think taking corrective action against the perpetrator may make things worse for the target of the harassment? I can't think of any reasonable reason why letting the perpetrator off the hook would result in the best outcome for the victims (note the plural!) of this incident.

@SophieSwett Retaliation mostly.  A person willing to say that in public probably isnt the best at self-control, and may not behave reasonably if punished.  Someone violent or dishonest can make your life worse in many ways even if you're not in the wrong at all.  It's not fair, but the LGBTQ employee might find it more practical to not escalate the issue.  I think management should at least work closely with the harassed employee to minimize those possibilities (like finding a different reason to get rid of the harasser, for example).

@lupe The big problem I see is that as far as the harasser is concerned, even if the company tries to disassociate it with the particular LGBTQ staff member, the harasser will still associate it with them.  It shouldn't be about the employee it was directed at, but it also shouldn't have been said at all.  There may be real-life situations that override what should happen in a fair and just world, which is why I think the opinion of the harassed employee is important.

@JMac Well, speaking for myself, I feel like if someone had something like this to me, the best way for the company to protect me from retaliation would be to not involve me at all, if that's feasible. It would be wonderful, in my opinion, if the company could truthfully say, "We're not taking corrective action against you because Sophie was upset; we're taking action because your words were inappropriate and violated company policies. In fact, we didn't even ask Sophie about this at all."

If you want to protect me from retaliation, then forcing me to make a decision that might provoke someone into retaliating against me is not the way to do it.

@SophieSwett Fair enough.  I'd definitely at least want management to warn me beforehand though.

I'd also argue "retaliation against someone you targeted after being warned by HR" is pretty much an instant dismissal kind of offense - it shows very clearly the person doing this does not intend to take the warning seriously.

At my one time at a very large company, retaliation was absolutely forbidden. The rule was that if someone retaliates against you, you don’t complain to HR, but to Legal. Even with this very serious insult, retaliation would be worse than the insult.

In other posts, I have been very critical of the Political wing of LGBT activism - So, what follows is from that standpoint.
I will start with the good - you did say something.
And that is where the good ends.
a Not Cool would be sufficient for a crass comment - such as "So, which one is the Husband" or similar.
Furthermore, you are only 2 drinks down in the evening, not that Alcohol is an excuse for saying stupid things - but there is a difference between something said at 6 pm after 1 beer and something said at 1 am after 11 Beers.
However - what was said was not an attempt at humor, not something that was ill-thought out - it was outright hostility.
I do not like to use the word Hate as it gets bandied about too much and often applied to things where it is incorrect or innapropriate (IMO) - however, in this scenario - Hate is absolutely the right word to use.
And I am afraid to say that your response was far too mild for what was said.
As others have said - I get it, you were shocked and didn't know what to do - and I trust this will be a learning experience.
This is an incident that needs to be reported to HR and Management. I want to draw a demarcation here to help:
Let us suppose that someone has personal issues with Homosexuality - say a deep religious conviction that it is a Moral Sin.
It is one thing to politely depart the table and choose not to engage with that individual or their partner - that would be acceptable (it is not ideal - as it becomes pretty obvious that there is an issue - which opens pandoras box...).
However - deciding to throw a Slur and leave - we have well and truly crossed the rubicon into the realm of serious HR issues.
Suffice to say - for the first question you asked - you underreacted.
To answer your second question - I am not one for platitudes after the fact and believe that actions are what truly speak loudly.
In an ideal world, you would politely apologize to the Lady and her Wife, then tell the employee that he is going to accompany you, whilst you go to HR and then escort him off the premises.

@Kilisi - Then it is assault and that is a whole different ball game.

@Kilisi - Do you think that defense would hold up in court: Why did you sucker punch him - Well your honor, he said something I didnt like... That is of course assuming that I dont double leg him and choke him out - either way, Heirachy or not - removing them from the event via a stop at HR is the right thing to do. If he wants to take a swing for whatever reason, then on his head be it.

2 drinks or ten drinks is the same - if you are out of control when drunk then you can’t drink. Simple as that.

Your reaction was understandable. In terms of doing more, I'd actually have asked if they wanted me to take it further and speak to my counterpart (the persons manager).
As a minority member wherever I go, I get a lot of abuse both direct and indirect. Most of the time it doesn't bother me and I have strategies to cope with it. It just gives me insights into people I can then factor in to any future interactions. It would bother me a lot more if people started drama uninvited over it for several reasons.
I don't want to be the office drama of the moment in a way that I cannot control or gauge the outcome or potential repercussions of. This would be especially true if it was my partners workplace and not even mine. I actually don't attend any of my wife's work functions. I know what I look like and I don't expect people to be tolerant or uncomfortable for my sake. It's their party.

Not asking the victim for permission to take it further has the advantage that the culprit cannot put the victim under pressure successfully.

@gnasher729 I don't see how that applies, or why it's the OP's problem.
